# Capture output log from Expect SCP Script

Tags: linux, bash, unix, expect, scp

I want to capture all output of scp automate script and move all output to log file

**My script:**

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn bash -c "scp /home/abc/pdf/105784/*.pdf labdb1@10.150.10.104:/home/labdb2/Desktop/l/" 
expect {
  -re ".*sword.*" {
   exp_send "password@\r"
  }
}
interact
```

**output:-**

```
./exp_test.sh 
spawn bash -c scp /home/abc/pdf/105784/*.pdf labdb1@10.150.10.104:/home/labdb2/Desktop/l/
labdb1@10.150.10.104's password:
104_105856_adhikari.pdf                             100%   10KB   9.8KB/s   00:00
134_105856_adhikari.pdf                             100%   10KB   9.9KB/s   00:00
135_105856_adhikari.pdf                             100%   10KB   9.8KB/s   00:00
193_105856_adhikari.pdf                             100%   10KB   9.8KB/s   00:00
```

i want all the output in a log file say name `scp_log.txt` also i do not want in a screen to display below thing

```
spawn bash -c scp /home/abc/pdf/105784/*.pdf labdb1@10.150.10.104:/home/labdb2/Desktop/l/
labdb1@10.150.10.104's password:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are interested in pure Expect based way, then you should use `log_user`.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
log_user 0; # Disabling logging to user window
log_file -a -noappend scp_log.txt
spawn bash -c "scp /home/abc/pdf/105784/*.pdf labdb1@10.150.10.104:/home/labdb2/Desktop/l/" 
expect {
  -re ".*sword.*" {
   exp_send "password@\r"
  }
}
interact
```

If you want to enable logging to user, then you can use `log_user 1` to do the same.

Comment: but still i am getting on screen output as : 104_105856_adhikari.pdf                                                                                                   100%   10KB   9.8KB/s   00:00
134_105856_adhikari.pdf                                                                                                   100%   10KB   9.9KB/s   00:00
135_105856_adhikari.pdf                                                                                                   100%   10KB   9.8KB/s   00:00

Answer (score 0):

IO redirection is a thing you want to use:

```
spawn bash -c "scp /home/abc/pdf/105784/*.pdf labdb1@10.150.10.104:/home/labdb2/Desktop/l/ &> scp_log.txt"
```

or just simply call the script as

```
./exp_test.sh &> scp_log.txt
```